# How to find which file holds specific value in S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

I can access S3 files only trough Glue and via Pyspark code as:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

How to find which file has specific value?
(e.g. to simulate cat and grep)

Goal is - if I search for word `test` - to give me list of S3 files that have this word. Files are GZipped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to grep into files stored in S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179573/how-to-grep-into-files-stored-in-s3)

Comment: No because do not have access to `aws s3` - only via Pyspark to the Glue Devendpoint (and see s3 as in the code snippet in question)..

Answer (score 1):

In pyspark, we can search contents in the file like below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name

input_path = "data/" # This can be a S3 location
data = spark.read.text(input_path).select(input_file_name(), "value").rdd
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df2 = df.filter(df["value"].contains("F1"))


>>> df.show()
+--------------------+--------------------+
|   input_file_name()|               value|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|file:///Users/hbo...|"`F1`","`F2`","`F3`"|
|file:///Users/hbo...|        "a","b","c"'|
|file:///Users/hbo...|         "d","e","f"|
|file:///Users/hbo...|      "F1","F2","F3"|
|file:///Users/hbo...|         "a","b","c"|
|file:///Users/hbo...|         "d","e","f"|
+--------------------+--------------------+

>>> df2 = df.filter(df["value"].contains("F1"))
>>> df2.show()
+--------------------+--------------------+
|   input_file_name()|               value|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|file:///Users/hbo...|"`F1`","`F2`","`F3`"|
|file:///Users/hbo...|      "F1","F2","F3"|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can only use `boto` and not the AWS CLI, your available functionality will be the same (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326408/difference-between-s3cmd-boto-and-aws-cli) on the differences between the CLI and boto).

Other questions exist on [how to grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179573/how-to-grep-into-files-stored-in-s3) [files in S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707646/how-to-grep-a-term-from-s3-and-output-object-name), using the CLI, and your approach will have to be similar:

1. Use the client to get the files' data locally (you probably want to do this file-by-file, or at least batched, assuming the files are somewhat large and/or numerous.
2. Use either a shell command call (literally `grep`, for example) or code logic to search the file.
3. Format your output nicely so each result is tied back to its original S3 file.

---

`cat` is even simpler than `grep`: take a target, get it via the client, and pipe it to standard out.